# Styling max-width for text area wrapper overlap the relative element

Tags: html, css

Here I have a wrapper div and inside two children div elements.
Wrapper div is having max-width of 500px and child div is having a textarea allowed to resize.
When I do resize , the relative element button gets overlapped .
Could someone explain what is happening and how to fix it ?
Is resize allowed to do more than max-width ?

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/saravananila/dk5z2h3r/9/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="text-area-element">
         <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button>
        BUTTON
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    max-width: 500px;
    display: flex;
}

.text-area-element {
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `max-width` constraint need to be applied to the textarea and not the div element

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 500px;
  display: flex;
}

.text-area-element {
  width: 250px;
}
.text-area-element textarea {
  max-width:100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="text-area-element">
    <textarea></textarea>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>
        BUTTON
        </button>
  </div>
</div>
```